# Timer tick implementation in c

Tags: c

I am doing some embedded system work and have a couple of question. I have a timer function which fires every 100ms. I now need to get the actual time once the system has started .

Currently my code is something like this:

```
struct timer
{

uint8_t millis_100;
uint8_t minute_455;
}


void tick()
{
//fires evry 100ms
timer_task.millis_100++;
}
```

However I am confused if this is the right approach since I will need to check if millis_100 overflowed to 0 and then increment it inside the ISR routine. If I need more than 455*2^8-1 then I would need to put another if statement in the ISR. IS this how system ticks are used to make software timers? Or is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about the timer overflowing, why not use an `unsigned long` variable ??
Check the timer implementation in linux kernel [timer.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/timer.c#L852), [timer.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/timer.h#L240)

For more details, read the section **The Timer API** in [LDD3/ch07](http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch07.pdf)

Comment: Do you know of anything which is simpler to implement and for smaller system based on microcontrollers?

Comment: For starters, use `uint32_t` if you are worried about the overflow. And if it still doesn't meet your requirement than keep another variable which you increment whenever you get an overflow on this one, as you mentioned in your quesiton.